# created no.de smartmachine without ssh key, can it be fixed?

Tags: ssh, node.js

I just got my coupon code for no.de and in my excitement I provisioned a smartmachine before adding my ssh key.

Now I don't know how to access it, and the only way I have found to add keys to an existing machine requires you to have ssh access.

Is there a way around this, or do I need to contact their technical support?

Comment: You may have shot yourself in the foot here. I recommend you leave a ticket with no.de

Comment: In case anyone else has this problem, after adding my key through the webpanel, I was able to access my machine, even though all the docs imply that this will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the following procedure:

http://wiki.joyent.com/display/node/How+to+use+SSH+Keys+with+Node+Smart+Machines#HowtouseSSHKeyswithNodeSmartMachines-InvalidSSHKeyonaNodeSmartMachines

I did the same and it solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you gonna have to contact their support.

[From their API docs](https://api.no.de/#PUT-/sshkeys/%3aid):

> It should be noted that changing an
>   sshkey record does not change any
>   currently provisioned SmartMachines.
>   To add or remove an ssh key from an
>   existing Smartmachine. one must login
>   and change their
>   ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

And I assume the same applies for https://no.de/sshkeys